# binding of reference to a value of type drops qualifiers MULTISET

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, multiset

CHotel& hotel = *it; I have problem on this row . When i'm trying to compile all code i get error binding of reference to a value of type drops qualifiers.

```
void addHotel(CHotel & hotel) {
        m_veriga.insert(hotel);         
        multiset<CHotel>::iterator it;


        for (it = m_veriga.begin(); it != m_veriga.end(); ++it)
        {
            CHotel& hotel = *it;
            cout << hotel.getHotelName() << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `m_veriga`?

Comment: multiset<CHotel> m_veriga; m_veriga = m_company

Comment: @vlladislav45 Please do not add code in the comments. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55515808/edit) your question instead to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing the iterator will give you a `const CHotel` reference in `set` and `multiset`.
So `CHotel const& hotel = *it;` will work.